# Error 500 al enviar POST con modulo GPRS SIM7100A, los datos llegan nulos

Tags: laravel-5, postgresql, http, arduino

e intenté hacer una publicación en la plataforma de Thingspeak pero la operación devuelve una solicitud incorrecta de 400, y probé una publicación con otra plataforma de prueba y obtuve 200ok, pero thingspeak no me ha funcionado, los comandos que uso son los siguientes:

```
POST /update? HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: api.thingspeak.com\r\n
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded \r\n
Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
\r\n\r\n
api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&field1=4
```

Estoy usando el terminal Putty con un scketch arduino como intermedio entre el módulo y la computadora, el código arduino es el siguiente:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial GPRS(7, 8); //R T
unsigned char buffer[64]; // buffer array for data recieve over serial port
int count=0;     // counter for buffer array 
void setup()
{
GPRS.begin(115200);               // the GPRS baud rate   
Serial.begin(115200);             // the Serial port of Arduino baud rate.
}
void loop()
{
if (GPRS.available())              // if date is comming from softwareserial 
port ==> data is comming from gprs shield
{
while(GPRS.available())          // reading data into char array 
{
 buffer[count++]=GPRS.read();     // writing data into array
 if(count == 64)break;
}
Serial.write(buffer,count);            // if no data transmission ends, write 
buffer to hardware serial port
clearBufferArray();              // call clearBufferArray function to clear 
the storaged data from the array
count = 0;                       // set counter of while loop to zero
}
if (Serial.available())            // if data is available on hardwareserial 
port ==> data is comming from PC or notebook
 GPRS.write(Serial.read());       // write it to the GPRS shield
 }
 void clearBufferArray()              // function to clear buffer array
 {
 for (int i=0; i<count;i++)
 { buffer[i]=NULL;}                  // clear all index of array with 
  command 
  }
  }
```

Usaba thingspeak para probar si la conexión era exitosa, pero probando en la plataforma que se usara en producción me devuelve error 500, interno del servidor, pero al momento de analizar lo que me devuelve puedo darme cuenta que los valores aparentemente llegan nulos, a continuación la respuesta del servidor de producción:
   [Codigo de error de servidor de produccion](https://pastebin.com/MNjGyDr4)

Obs: estoy utilizando un servidor web ngnix, base de datos postgres y un apiRest hecho en laravel 5

Estoy utilizando el módulo SIM7100A con arduino, envío los comandos de manera manual AT con Putty, e realizado pruebas con postman e inserta los datos satisfactoriamente

[Documentación comandos AT SIM7100](http://www.mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/documents/sim7100_at_command_manual_v1.00.pdf) pagina 417 se encuentran la parte de envíos HTTP

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he logrado!
El problema se encontraba al no agregar el Content Length dentro de la estructura de envio. Como no enviaba la longitud de la cadena me reconocía como nulo.

Comment: Excelente, te recomiendo que coloques tu respuesta como aceptada, con esto se entenderá que la pregunta fue respondida correctamente.